# Trying to understand regular expression from legacy project

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In one codebase (PHP) I'm working on currently there is this regular expression:

```
!([a-z0-9]*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})
```

Which supposedly should match something like this:

```
a1213asddaa13124312ada.12ws
```

And yet it does not happen. Matching occurs only with this expression:

```
([a-z0-9]*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})
```

Can anybody clarify?

Comment: Your first regex has `!` at start

Comment: As far as I know "!" should not be a meta-character in PHP regex, so it was probably trying to match the "!" character exactly. You can see [this](https://regex101.com) website to test your regex in different language flavors.

Comment: Thanks Nicola. That was it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` has no special meaning. It'll match a literal exclamation mark. `a1213asddaa13124312ada.12ws` does not start with one.